# ELF and processor specific aspects of dynamic linking

Tags: dynamic, linker, relocation

I am trying to understand the process of dynamic linking, in detail.
For the purpose, I tried digging into .got section of ELF.

q.1 : I read in ELF Standard 1.2(Appendix) that Global offset table's format and interpretation are processor specific. Can some body please help me, why we dont have standard for this as well and why it has to be processor specific?

q.2 : Can someome point to a tutorial or some thing, where I can get some understanding of operations of a dynamic linker on a live process, examining the contents of .got, .got.plt sections in each step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This one](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) covers quite a lot about shared libraries on linux

Comment: Not really, but at a guess, the GOT is (or atleast can be used) directly as pointers or offsets added to actual pointers, and pointers can easily have different representation among systems - the obvious is 32 bit vs 64 bit systems.